# How to use iframe within a jQuery slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i have a full-screen background slideshow which uses jQuery, with about 7 images and also an iframe that displays a youtube video.

When the iframe slide comes along it only shows the bottom bit with the rest of the page being white.

When the next slide comes along the iframe does not fade out and remains there until the slide show resets (to the first slide)

Also the iframe is non responsive, so when i click on it doesnt play.

Please help

```
        HTML

        <div id="slider">
        <img id="1" src="Images/IMG_2615.png" style="hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
        <img id="2" src="Images/IMG_2616.png" style="hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
        <img id="3" src="Images/IMG_2619.png" "hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
        <iframe id="4" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KVwSP51KVO8?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" class="youtube-video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <img id="5" src="Images/IMG_2620.png" "hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
        <img id="6" src="Images/IMG_4189.JPG" "hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
        <img id="7" src="Images/IMG_4245.JPG" "hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
        <img id="8" src="Images/IMG_4283.JPG" "hight:1048px; width:1571px;" alt="" />
    </div>
    <!-- Background Slideshow -->`

CSS

#slider {
overflow: hidden;
/* Set rules to fill background */
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;}

#slider > img {
float: left;
display: none;
//height: 1048px;
//width: 1571px;}

#slider iframe {
float: left;
//display: none;}



JS

 sliderInt = 1;
 sliderNext = 2;

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#slider>Img#1').fadeIn(1000);
 startSlider();
 });


function startSlider() {
count = $('#slider>Img').size();

loop = setInterval(function () {

    if(sliderNext > count) {
        sliderNext = 1;
        sliderInt = 1;
    }

    $('#slider>Img').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#slider>Img#'+ sliderNext).fadeIn(1000);

    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
}, 7000)
```

}

Comment: drop the img+iframe in a ul than change the slider to target only the li of the ul not the img as you are doing now

Comment: @madalinivascu I have put the img+iframe into a ul but the same thing happened so i decided to resize the i frame and that seemed to work and also the i frame is fading out now so thats good, but now for some reason my imgs will fade out but not in instead they just appear, also the iframe is still non responsive so when i click on it noting happens. also my imgs are not fitted correctly how do i do this i tried putting the style tag within the img tags and also tried the setting the width and hight withing the css but nothing worked :(